# How to add Submenus to TActionMainMenuBar programatically?

Tags: delphi, menu, tactionmanager

I have been developing a VCL program and am adding code for placing a 'Recent Files' dropdown submenu listing a group of files. For this program I have populated a tActionManager and a tActionMainMenuBar. I have created similar menus before using tmenuitems in a standard tMainMenu component generating the list of recent file submenu items in the FormCreate event procedure. However, I am uncertain how to go about this dynamically using the Action components and have not found any examples to serve as a model.

Can anyone provide an example of how this is done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To illustrate this I created a simple application with an action manager as TActionMainToolBar and added a simple file menu using standard items Open, Save As and Exit (no separators) plus a speed button.

The speed button adds two separators and a file action, and its OnClick event looks like this...

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  iActionClientItem : TActionClientItem;
  iFileAction : TCustomAction;
begin
  //  Edit2.Text := BaseToBase( Edit1.Text, SpinEdit1.Value , SpinEdit2.Value );
  ActionManager1.AddSeparator( ActionManager1.FindItemByAction(FileExit1), FALSE );
  iActionClientItem := ActionManager1.AddSeparator( ActionManager1.FindItemByAction(FileExit1) );
  iFileAction :=  TCustomAction.Create( self ); // we want to put in same collection
  iFileAction.Caption := 'Fred';
  // etc.. to build what is wanted
  iActionClientItem := ActionManager1.AddAction( iFileAction, iActionClientItem )  ;
end;
```

Running the program and opening the file menu shows the three expected entries. After clicking the button (don't do it twice - it is justy to demonstrate how it works) you get the two separators and a new menu sub item with the caption 'Fred' Note that you may need to give it a unique name if you need to do any handling of it.

### Edit

Building sub menus can be done basically the same way but with a little trick of adding an unused and not visible item not through the action manager. It doesn't have to be done this way - it is just a simple way to get what we want.

This code shows how to achieve this:

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  iActionClientItem : TActionClientItem;
  iSubMenuItem : TActionClientItem;
  iFileAction : TCustomAction;
  iChildMenu : TActionBarItem;
begin
  ActionManager1.AddSeparator( ActionManager1.FindItemByAction(FileExit1), FALSE );
  iActionClientItem := ActionManager1.AddSeparator( ActionManager1.FindItemByAction(FileExit1) );
  iFileAction :=  TCustomAction.Create( self ); // we want to put in same collection
  iFileAction.Caption := 'Fred';
  // etc.. to build what is wanted
  iActionClientItem := ActionManager1.AddAction( iFileAction, iActionClientItem )  ;

  //*********************************
  // Build sub menu (from Fred) - stage 1 add the visual element - a new action bar
  iChildMenu :=  ActionManager1.ActionBars.Add;
  iActionClientItem.ChildActionBar := iChildMenu.ActionBar;

  // we add a dummy entry that we can build from.
  // We could set the properties manually, but when we use the action manager
  // it does that automatically, so it is easier just to set this item to not visible
  // then use action manager to do the rest.
  iSubMenuItem := iActionClientItem.Items.Add;
  iSubMenuItem.Visible := FALSE;

  // Now the real build...

  iFileAction :=  TCustomAction.Create( self ); // we want to put in same collection
  iSubmenuItem := ActionManager1.AddAction( iFileAction, iSubMenuItem );
  iSubmenuItem.Caption := 'Fred 1';
  // etc

  iFileAction :=  TCustomAction.Create( self ); // we want to put in same collection
  iSubmenuItem := ActionManager1.AddAction( iFileAction, iSubMenuItem );
  iSubmenuItem.Caption := 'Fred 2';
  // etc
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am not clear on how to add an action such as 'File 1' as a submenu item to another action such as 'open' or 'Fred'.

Comment: @Ashlar - sorry I am away from my computer now until tomorrow. I will attempt to expand then.

Comment: It Works! Great simple example